# Play live streaming, which uses RTMP protocol and hide actual IP with a subdomain of website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, streaming, rtmp, wowza

I have to play live streaming, which uses RTMP protocol and I want to hide my actual IP with a subdomain of my website.

I have an IP i.e 46.x.x.x and when i use code give below, It works:

```
<object width="550" height="400" data="http://www.hdwebplayer.com/standalone-demo/components/com_webplayer/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="http://www.hdwebplayer.com/standalone-demo/components/com_webplayer/player.swf" name="movie">
<param value="opaque" name="wmode"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param value="&amp;stretch=uniform&amp;type=rtmp&amp;streamer=rtmp://46.x.x.x/live&amp;video=mychannel&amp;duration=9999&amp;autoStart=true" name="flashvars">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
</object>
```

but when I try to access it using subdomain e.g. test.mysite.com at place of ip address, it does not works.

Code i Tried is:

```
<object width="550" height="400" data="http://www.hdwebplayer.com/standalone-demo/components/com_webplayer/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="http://www.hdwebplayer.com/standalone-demo/components/com_webplayer/player.swf" name="movie">
<param value="opaque" name="wmode"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param value="&amp;stretch=uniform&amp;type=rtmp&amp;streamer=rtmp://test.mysite.com/live&amp;video=<?php echo $ch; ?>&amp;duration=9999&amp;autoStart=true" name="flashvars">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
</object>
```

I know that I have to change some apache configurations some where. But I dont know what code has to be written and in wich file ([This](http://www.actionscriptdeveloper.co.uk/running-apache-and-wowzaflash-media-serverred5-on-port-80-at-the-same-time/) aricle suggested, this does not work in .htaccess)

So can anybody help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your DNS setting to make test.mysite.com point to 46.xx.xx.xx instead of to your apache webserver.

(Note that you can therefor not use test.example.com to serve webpages too. In other words; test.example.com should be an unused subdomain.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to say thanks to Gerben ... :)

I have added an A Record using DNS Manager in Cpanel of my website i.e. **http:// mysite.com/cpanel**

with following settings:

Name: test
(It will automatically detect already created sub domain i.e. test.mysite.com. If it does not detect it automatically, tehn enter full subdomain name e.g. test.mysite.com [In my case])

Address:  46.x.x.x

Then click Add a record Button.

Thats all about the magic. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really hiding your IP address by doing this. Anybody can still do an nslookup on the hostname (test.mysite.com) and determine the IP address (46.x.y.z)